# Button to display different messages before proceeding

Tags: apex, urlhacking, button, conditional

I have two buttons. **Button1** and **Button2**. Clicking Button1 button will show an intermediate page for the user to proceed  *"Are you sure you want to Action1?"*

```
       if(abc.checkFullAccess(Obj.OwnerId))
        {
            //Displays a confirmation message
            pgeMsg = Label.CL1234;//"Are you sure you want to proceed?"
            sevrity = 'confirm';
        }
```

Button2 button has exactly same function as clone but the intermediate page should show "Do you want to Action2?". Both Button1 and Button2 buttons on clicking open up a **VF_Page** whose controller is **VC_Page** which has the above code. Following is the code when I click Button2..

> https://c.cs01.visual.force.com/apex/VF_Page?scontrolCaching=1&id=axaxalxakdad

I'm unable to think of a criteria for the above **if** function.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide an additional parameter in the URL:

```
/apex/VF_Page?scontrolCaching=1&id=axaxalxakdad&mode=revise
```

and check that value in the controller:

```
if (abc.checkFullAccess(Obj.OwnerId))
{
    String mode = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('mode');
    if (mode == 'proceed') {
        pgeMsg = Label.CL1234;//"Are you sure you want to proceed?"
    } else if (mode == 'revise') {
        pgeMsg = Label.CL5678;//"Do you want to revise?";
    }
    sevrity = 'confirm';
}
```